# Can't access value inside of props object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I am unable to access the value inside the year and month variables, as it returns an object.

```
getClassStatus () {
        var year = (this.props.year).toString();
        var month = (this.props.month).toString();
        var day = this.props.day;
        request
            .get('example.com/getRosterCount')
            .query({ year: {year} })
            .query({ month: {month} })
            .query({ day: {day} })
            .query({ time: 10 })
            .end((err, resp) => {
                if (!err) {
                    switch (resp.text) {
                        case "6":
                            this.setState({ status: 'full' });
                            break;
                        case "closed": 
                            this.setState({ status: 'closed' });
                            break;
                        case "booked":
                            this.setState({ status: 'booked' });
                            break;
                        default:
                            this.setState({ status: 'available' });
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

I have tried accessing the value as I would with any other object.

Eg.

```
var year = (this.props.year).toString(); // {year: '2019'}

console.log(year.year); // undefined
```

But it always returns `undefined`

How can I access this value?

Edit:
Here's the server side code

```
app.get('/getRosterCount', (req, res) => {
    var year = req.query.year; // {year: '2019'}
    var month = req.query.month; // {month: '5'}
    var day = req.query.day;
    var time = req.query.time;

    console.log(year, month, day, time);

    // Add padding to month and day if needed so they always have 2 digits
    if (month.length == 1) {
        month = "0"+month;
    }

    if (day.length == 1) {
        day = "0"+day;
    }

    var dateString = year+'-'+month+'-'+day;

    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) throw err;
        connection.query("SELECT _fkUserID FROM roster WHERE (date = ? AND time LIKE ?) OR (date = ? AND time = ?)", 
        [
            dateString,
            time+'%',
            dateString,
            time
        ],
        function(error, rows, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            else {
                console.log(rows);
                console.log(rows.length);
                res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
                res.send(rows.length.toString());
                console.log(this.sql);
            }
        });

        connection.release();
    });
});
```

The query never goes through because it ends up being this:

`SELECT _fkUserID FROM roster WHERE (date = '[object Object]-[object Object]-[object Object]' AND time LIKE '10%') OR (date = '[object Object]-[object Object]-[object Object]' AND time = '10')`

Comment: `this.props.year` should yield a value, not an object.  You shouldn't need to `toString` the value here.

Answer (score 3):

If you call `toString()` you cant access the value because `year` is not an object anymore.

`// obj.toString() === '[object Object]'`

Try without `toString()`.

Comment: You're right, `toString()` is unnecessary. But even when removed the server-side query contains objects. `SELECT _fkUserID FROM roster WHERE (date = '[object Object]-[object Object]-[object Object]' AND time LIKE '10%') OR (date = '[object Object]-[object Object]-[object Object]' AND time = '10')` I will add server side code to post

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `request` in your code, but you pass to your query an object which contains an object - `.query({ year: { year: 2019 } })`, try passing the only the value of year.

Comment: maybe you should consider using `JSON.stringify` https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp. `obj.toString()` will give you `'[object Object]'`, `JSON.stringify(obj)` will convert the object to a string, it will give you `{"year": 2019}"`

Comment: I will try that @OlivierBoissé . Obviously sending just the value rather than the whole object is the optimal solution. Accessing the object server-side is just a band-aid for now.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by removing the brackets around the variable.

Changed

```
   request
        .get('example.com/getRosterCount')
        .query({ year: {year} })
        .query({ month: {month} })
        .query({ day: {day} })
```

to

```
    request
        .get('example.com/getRosterCount')
        .query({ year: year })
        .query({ month: month })
        .query({ day: day })
```

Now I get the actual value in the URL rather than an object.